# Einsum very slow to compute c distance

Tags: numpy, numpy-einsum

I'm computing mahalanobis distance via np.einsum:

```
np.einsum('nj,jk,nk->n', delta, VI, delta)
```

where VI, the covariance matrix's inverse, is `783 x 783` and delta is `6000 x 783`. This line takes 10s on my 2016 Macbook Pro to execute. How can I make this go faster?

I have to compute this line 200k to 300k times. Vectorization may not be an option because VI is different for each class.

Comment: Use `optimize` flag?

Comment: With `optimize=True` time drops from 10s to 400ms.

Comment: When `optimize=True` einsum computes the greedy path. When `optimize='optimal'` it takes longer but computes a better calculation path (might the same in this case). You can pre-compute this `path`, however, if the dimension of your arrays don't change and supply `optimize=path`, which is probably the best use case here so it doesn't need to compute the same thing over and over. See the last example in numpy einsum docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for Einsum, you can use dot and elementwise products, and a sum instead:

```
VI = np.random.rand(783, 783)
delta = np.random.rand(6000, 783)

%timeit np.einsum('nj,jk,nk->n', delta, VI, delta)
# 7.05 s ± 89.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit np.sum((delta @ VI) * delta, axis=-1)
# 90 ms ± 4.72 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

out_1 = np.einsum('nj,jk,nk->n', delta, VI, delta)
out_2 = np.sum((delta @ VI) * delta, axis=-1)
np.allclose(out_1, out_2)
# True
```

### How did I arrive at this?

`nj,jk->nk` is a dotproduct:

```
tmp_1 = np.einsum('nj,jk->nk', delta, VI)
tmp_2 = delta @ VI
np.allclose(tmp_1, tmp_2)  # True
```

`nk,nk->nk` is an elementwise product:

```
tmp_3 = np.einsum('nk,nk->nk', tmp_1, delta)
tmp_4 = tmp_2 * delta
np.allclose(tmp_3, tmp_4)  # True
```

and `nk->n` is a sum over the last axis:

```
tmp_5 = np.einsum('nk->n', tmp_3)
tmp_6 = np.sum(tmp_4, axis=-1)
np.allclose(tmp_5, tmp_6)  # True
```

### Vectorizing `VI`

You will notice that vectorizing `VI` along the first axis will *just work*:

```
# Vectorized `VI`
nd_VI = np.random.rand(3, 783, 783)
# Unvectorized `VI`, for comparison
VI = nd_VI[0, :]
delta = np.random.rand(6000, 783)

out = np.sum((delta @ VI) * delta, axis=-1)
out.shape
# (6000,)

nd_out = np.sum((delta @ nd_VI) * delta, axis=-1)
nd_out.shape
# (3, 6000)

# Result of vectorized and unvectorized `IV` are the same
np.allclose(out, nd_out[0, :])
# True
```

### Vectorizing `VI` and `delta` elementwise

Same with vectorizing both `VI` and `delta`, just add the same number of elements to the beginning of `VI` and `delta`

```
# Vectorized `VI`
nd_VI = np.random.rand(3, 783, 783)
# Unvectorized `VI`, for comparison
VI = nd_VI[0, ...]
# Vectorized `delta`
nd_delta = np.random.rand(3, 6000, 783)
# Unvectorized `delta`, for comparison
delta = nd_delta[0, ...]

out = np.sum((delta @ VI) * delta, axis=-1)
out.shape
# (6000,)

nd_out = np.sum((nd_delta @ nd_VI) * nd_delta, axis=-1)
nd_out.shape
# (3, 6000)

# Result of vectorized and unvectorized `IV` are the same
np.allclose(out, nd_out[0, ...])
# True
```

### Vectorizing `VI` and `delta` independently

Or, if you want to calculate the Mahalanobis distance of every element in `VI` with every possible element in `delta`, you can use broadcasting:

```
# Vectorized `VI`, note the extra empty dimension (where `delta` has 3)
nd_VI = np.random.rand(4, 1, 783, 783)
# Unvectorized `VI`, for comparison
VI = nd_VI[0, 0, ...]
# Vectorized `delta`, note the extra empty dimension (where `VI` has 4)
nd_delta = np.random.rand(1, 3, 6000, 783)
# Unvectorized `delta`, for comparison
delta = nd_delta[0, 0, ...]

out = np.sum((delta @ VI) * delta, axis=-1)
out.shape
# (6000,)

nd_out = np.sum((nd_delta @ nd_VI) * nd_delta, axis=-1)
nd_out.shape
# (4, 3, 6000)

# Result of vectorized and unvectorized `IV` are the same
np.allclose(out, nd_out[0, 0, ...])
# True
```

Comment: Think, we can go a bit more with `np.einsum('nk,nk->n', delta.dot(VI),delta)`.

Comment: @NilsWerner Is nd_VI holding 3 different covariance matrices?

Comment: @saad yes, its shape is 3x783x783

Comment: I meant `np.einsum('nk,nk->n', delta.dot(VI),delta)` could be a bit more performant than using `np.sum(..)` version.

Comment: @Divakar ah ok! I checked, they're the exact same speed.

Comment: `np.einsum_path('nj,jk,nk->n',delta,VI,delta,optimize=True) ` discovers this same path,  'jk,nj->kn' followed by 'kn,nk->n'

Comment: @NilsWerner Shouldn't delta also be in 3 dimensions, so it holds the corresponding values for nd_VI?

Comment: @saad I thought you only changed `VI`, but held `delta` constant? If that isn't the case then it should have 3 dimensions, too, yes.

Comment: @NilsWerner Thank you. Is it possible for nd_delta's slices to have different shapes?

Comment: Oh wait, different shapes? Then no.